# Should I say "The Trump Administration restricted" or "The Trump administration restricted"?

Tags: adjectives, capitalization

If **administration** is modifying a president should it be capitalized? Is it incorrect to say *The Trump administration restricted immigration from 7 countries*?

Comment: In this case, "Trump" tells us _which_ administration, making his name the modifier, no?

Comment: In any event, you couldn't say either of them, since capitalization is inaudible and therefore not part of English.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding U.S. President capitalization](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44848/understanding-u-s-president-capitalization)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct phrasing is **Trump administration** based on the APA Style Manual. I also noticed that the majority of news articles don't capitalize *administration*.

[https://writingexplained.org/ap-style/ap-style-administration#:~:text=Do%20I%20Capitalize%20Presidential%20Administration,particular%20administration%20should%20be%20lowercase](https://writingexplained.org/ap-style/ap-style-administration#:%7E:text=Do%20I%20Capitalize%20Presidential%20Administration,particular%20administration%20should%20be%20lowercase).